# How "caring" and "who's in charge" are related to each other?

Tags: small-soldiers-1998

In Sci-fi movie Small Soldiers (1998), Delivery guy delivered toys from Joe to the company who once send it to the Joe:

> Delivery guy: I think that's all of Friday's delivery. Why did they
>   want it back?
>
> Joe: You know the clowns that make these decisions. They don't **care**
>   we're standing around freezing, in the middle of the night...as long
>   as everyone knows **who's in charge**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the phrasing here. Joe is grumpy about the toys having been recalled at short notice, requiring a late collection. He accuses the  executives who made the choice (office-based pen-pushers) of lacking feeling for the hard working stiff (him) who actually has to carry out the recall.

> You know the [Toy company executive] clowns that make these decisions
>   [to recall the toys at short notice] don't care [that] we're standing
>   around freezing as long as everyone [like us] knows who's in charge
>   [e.g. them]